# How to divide a pie between persons in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm

I have got two arrays:

- An array describing what part of the pie a person of a given index `[0...n]` has.

  Sample:

  ```
  array(0.2, 0.3, 0.5)
  ```
- An array describing if a person is present

  ```
  array(1, 0, 1)
  ```

I need an idea on how to divide the whole pie between all present persons.

Could anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sum the proportions of present people.
   In this case:

   ```
   0.2 + 0.5 = 0.7
   ```
2. Divide 1 by it

   ```
   1 / 0.7 = 1.43
   ```
3. Multiply the proportions by the result

   ```
   0.2 * 1.43 = 0.28
   0.5 * 1.43 = 0.72
   ```

Comment: Thanx. I just got that when writting question, but still it is a good answer.

Comment: BTW this question would fit more on math.stackexchange